# malformed syntax using CURL for OAuth

Tags: curl, oauth, oauth-2.0, openam

I'm trying to get my simple OAuth flow to work using the curl commands, for authorization i'm trying the below curl, it's ending up in 400 and the reson is below.
Trying this:
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "response_type=code&client_id=TestClient&redirect_uri=https://example.test.com/test" https://openam.example.com/auth/oauth2/authorize

Result:
"FAILED","400","{""reason"":""The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax""}","2","MILLISECONDS","OAuth","/"

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Edit your question so that we can see the exact curl command. Notice the `{}` in the toolbar. This allows you to format your text as code. The problem is that you are not building the data parameters correctly for a POST. Here is an article that I wrote that explains how to use curl with OAuth https://www.jhanley.com/google-oauth-2-0-testing-with-curl/

Answer (score 1):

You have to use HTTP GET instead of HTTP POST , please see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.1

Comment: I did used GET and it looks like working but I don't see anything in response, I see success in splunk too but I don't see the authorization code.

Comment: The authorization code is only issued after the Authorization Server authenticated the resource owner, please see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.1

So OpenAM will actually send back a redirect to the Login URL.

Comment: Is there a way I can have the user login using curl only and continue with the flow ?

Comment: If you run all the requests (including cookies) as a browser then, of course it will work. OpenAM offers REST based auth API as well. Normally users are also asked for consent, depending on the AM version 'implicit consent' is configurable on an OAuth2 client basis.

Comment: Thank you all and appreciate the responses.